# Automotive power steering unit connector identification

Tags: connector, identification, automotive

I would like to request some help to identify the following connector (at least the manufacturer and connector family type):

- located inside the Toyota Camry 2018 Hybrid Power Steering Rack Pinion (marked with 2.)
- it is connecting the torque sensor with the EPS motor
- the type of the power steering rack pinion is: JJ501-003031

Thank you in advance,

Connector marked with 2.:
[image]

Front view:
[image: connector_front]

Side view:
[image: connector side]

Identification sticker:
[image]

Comment: Have you asked Toyota?

Comment: Yes, I was told to replace the whole power steering rack pinion assembly.

Comment: So that usually comes complete... why are you looking for the plug separately?

Comment: We are producing some R&D features which includes spoofing the torque sensor signal, working with c-eps systems were easier to find the proper connectors since those are not splash proof and more common.

Comment: Could you find a scrap yard that has one of these cars?  You could get the cable/connector off the body/frame.

Comment: Yes a salvaged steering rack pinnion system is on the ways already, but I am also interested on the wire2wire mating pair of the connector, this is why I am looking for a good guess for the connector family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automotive connectors may very well be proprietary designs done by the company itself or on special sourcing contract with a connector manufacturer. As such it is common that you will not be able to independently source the connectors yourself.

A secondary concern is that these cables also use special crimp on contacts that require very expensive tooling to reliably apply the contacts.

It is an unfortunate byproduct of the mass production world where it is next to impossible to get individual replacement parts and instead have to purchase whole subassemblies instead. Have you considered visiting a auto salvage yard to see if you can get a used cable assembly?

Comment: Yes a salvaged steering rack pinnion system is on the ways already, but I am also interested on the wire2wire mating pair of the connector, this is why I am looking for a good guess for the connector family.